# What is the point of two fuses in series?

Tags: safety, fuses

I've got a 12V power adaptor (3.8A). And it got two fuses in it (T3.15AL250V, 3AL250V, one of which (3.15A) has blown, along with mosfet, current sense resistor, 450V cap, and IC. I replaced all failed parts, except the fuse (soldered jumper, since I don't have 3.15A fuse for now).

[image]
[image]

What is the point of two fuses in series? I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: For me it looks like the 3 amps fuse is parallel to your cap. So you have a main fuse for the whole circuit (3.15 amps) and a fuse for a part of the circuit (3 amps)

Comment: It looks like there is a wire link instead of one of the fuses.

Comment: @HandyHowie, that link on right hand I did solder, as I mentioned in the question description. When I have 3.15A fuse I will solder it in

Comment: @Eggi, no, the fuses are in series, connected to one of the mains leads. One lead of high voltage capacitor is connected between fuses, and other lead in connected to another mains' lead.

Comment: Maybe one of the fuse (the 3.15A) is useless when the jumper is open but necessary when it's closed? In other words, is there a split of traces or connections at the upper right corner of the pcb (first photo)?

Comment: Where does it say in your description that you used a wire link instead of a fuse?

Comment: @HandyHowie, ok, I've only mentioned that I didn't replaced the fuse

Comment: @Fredled, what do you mean by "jumper is open"? Three thing are connected to the node on upper right corner of pcb (photo below): 3A fuse, 3.15A fuse (but I soldered a jumper, since I didn't have a fuse), high voltage capacitor. There is nothing comming in or out that node

Comment: You sure that's a cap?  Looks like a MOV

Comment: Just speculating: Could it be that the circuit is protected by a fast-acting fuse, while the capacitor has a slow fuse so the inrush current doesn't immediately blow it (while a defective capacitor would)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Qeeet On the first picture, you drew the jumper and the 3.15A fuse as separate objects linking different node (?). Anyway, you have one trace protected by one fuse, another one protected by another fuse. The explanation is that the 3A fuse blows when the MOV (it's definetly a MOV, not a cap) clamps under accidental voltage surge. The 3.15A doesn't blow in this situation whereas it would blow when there is a short circuit but no voltage surge. Probably the 3A is fast acting, since in case of voltage surge you want to react ASAP. And the 3.15A is slow acting as temporary overcurrent may happen in normal situations and become critical only when it lasts more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Possible option: The critical current of the fuse when it blows up is difficult to manufacture exactly and there is no way to verify its accuracy. If you will put 2 fuses in series, they will disconnect the circuit on the minimum of the critical currents of these two. In case if the blow up current of a fuse will happen to be bigger than the nominal, the other one will raise the chance that the critical current will not be exceeded.